# Mining with ethermine, still nothing showing up in MyEtherWallet

Tags: ether, myetherwallet

Just a few days ago, I started mining with Claymore's Dual Miner on EtherMine.org. I have double checked my address on my batch file, etc. but there is still nothing showing up in my 'wallet'. Am I doing something wrong?

By the way, I am still pretty new to this, so don't judge!

Answer (score 1):

Most mining pools have a "minimum payout", which means your account must have a minimum amount of ETH earned before it will send it to your wallet.

I believe the lowest most mining pools support is .1 ETH, but you should check your own settings on the mining pool.